# Default file for Apache localhost

Tags: php, html, apache2, lamp

I have apache2 installed. When i type http://localhost it goes to a file http://localhost/class/index.php . How do i change it to say http://localhost/index.html or any other page? Which file will I find the setting to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean it **redirects** to another URL pointing to another subdirectory?

Comment: Yeah. I suppose its a redirection :). How do I ensure that it does not redirect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache will not trigger HTTP redirections unless you instruct it to do so.

My advice is that you open your favourite text editor and search for the `class` string in the following locations:

- `*.conf` files inside the Apache installation directory.
- `.htaccess` files inside your HTML directores.

If that fails to find anything, you could also search for `header()` calls in your `*.php`  code.

Answer (score 5):

Find the [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive in your Apache configuration file (httpd.conf) or add it to a .htaccess file and change it to look like this if you want to limit your default index file to just *index.html*:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

You can also include more resources and they will be used in the order given, e.g

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

would display the *index.html* file first if both *index.html* and *index.php* existed.

Don't forget to restart Apache if you made the change to the httpd.conf file.

Look at the [mod_dir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) documentation for more information.

Comment: I did that as above. /var/www has only index.html file right now. However when I access http:// localhost, it still tries to open a non existent file http:// localhost/class/index.php

Comment: Did you try restarting Apache?

Comment: Yeah .. i did restart apache.

Comment: Make sure a index.html file exists in your root, check that index.html appears first after the `DirectoryIndex` directive and there are no more occurrences of it in the file, make sure you restart Apache and ensure there are no .htaccess files overriding the `DirectoryIndex` directive. Is there a .htaccess file in the root? If so, post it's contents in the question please.

Comment: In my root (which is /var/www since i use Ubuntu) there is only 1 file called index.html. I have restarted apache and there is no .htaccess file in the root. Thanks!

Comment: Double check each point in my previous comment, I have a feeling there may be more than one occurrence of `DirectoryIndex` in your `httpd.conf` or any other configuration files that it may include.